# Strange behaviour with string passing to rpy2 - deleting leading zeros from string

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, string, rpy2

I am trying to call a python string variable within a rpy2 script. The variable is supposed to have the shape "01".

I encountered the following behaviour:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
string_to_pass = "01"
robjects.r('''print(paste("Output from R with format and paste:",{}))'''.format(string_to_pass))
```

will give the following output:

```
[1] "Output from R with format and paste: 1"
```

Note, that the leading zero of the string was cut off.

On the other side, these lines will work as expected:

```
print("Output from python with format: {}".format(string_to_pass))
robjects.r('''print("Output from R with format: {}")'''.format(string_to_pass))
robjects.r('''print(paste("Output from R with pasting a string:", "01"))''')
```

with the output:

```
Output from python with format: 01
[1] "Output from R with format: 01"
[1] "Output from R with pasting a string: 01"
```

Can sombody please explain what is happening here, only when combining python .format() and r paste(), and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by saying

```
string_to_pass = "'01'"
robjects.r('''print(paste("Output from R with format and paste:",{}))'''.format(string_to_pass))
```

Note the additional inner quotation marks which seem to be important for R to recognize it as a string aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the strings passed to rpy2 for evaluation as R code should make what is happening clear.

In the first case that string of R code is:

```
print(paste("Output from R with format and paste:", 01))
```

The number 01 is a 1, and R will print it has a such. To have a leading zero one should use an R number formatting function.

In the second case it is:

```
print(paste("Output from R with format and paste: 01"))
```